# Retrieving user's AAD App Role in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, powerapps

We have registered an `Azure AD App` and updated the manifest file to include 2 app roles, thereafter assigned user to the App Role.

```
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Approvers can approve the information",
        "displayName": "Approver",
        "id": "8f29f99b-5c77-4fba-a310-4a5c0574e8ff",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "approver"
    }
```

The manifest file also has,

```
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
"groupMembershipClaims": "All",
```

The AAD app has both enabled `ID Token` and `Access Token`

In `Azure API Management`, we have enabled `OAuth2` with following properties:

- Authorization Code
- Access token sending mechanism: Authorization Header
- Client ID / Secret as retrieved from AAD App

When we login to Developer Portal and test the API, we are able to retrieve the AAD JWT token; however, `Roles` assigned to user are not included in the token even if the user is already assigned application role.

```
{
  "aud": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
  "iat": 1559283639,
  "nbf": 1559283639,
  "exp": 1559287539,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "amr": [
    "rsa",
    "mfa"
  ],
  "appid": "dbccd1a6-1dab-4013-8601-ee6054b5a12",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "deviceid": "d1c0faa8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7f2a791387a7",
  "family_name": "Gxxxx",
  "given_name": "Pxxxxxxx",
  "name": "Pxxxxxxx Gxxxx",
  "oid": "741232d8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-aed51374ec7a",
  "scp": "email offline_access openid profile",
  "sub": "",
  "tenant_region_scope": "WW",
  "tid": "72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
  "unique_name": "email@host.com",
  "upn": "email@host.com",
  "uti": "rMaJcHJTLUKFBvkPXLpDAQ",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

This token is generated from PowerApps custom connector using `OAuth2`

[image: Custom Connector]

The `backend API` is expecting the role information as well.

Is there something wrong in the configuration? How do we also retrieve `Application Roles` for the user?

Comment: Seems like the token is acquired for some built-in API. You need to make sure the resource for the API is set to your API's client id / app id URI. The aud claim in the token doesn't seem like a client id for one of your APIs.

Comment: Correct. Right now I am testing the generation of token from APIM Developer Portal

Comment: Roles are only included in tokens that are meant for the app that defined those roles.

Comment: The App ID in the token is the same App ID for which the roles are defined in the manifest

Comment: The audience (aud) needs to be that, the appid claim doesn't matter.

Comment: Aha. So if a PowerApp is invoking these APIs using some connector which will also have an internal aud, there's no way to retrieve app role in the backend API?

Comment: No. If the app acquires the access token *for the API* (specifies resource/scope to be that API), the access token will contain the roles.

Comment: We are receiving aud as `https://management.core.windows.net/` from PowerApp even if the resource is our `AAD App ID URI` and scope is `openid`

Comment: Don't know about PowerApps, sorry. The PowerApp is requesting a token for Azure Resource Management then, which is not what you want.